# How to use column default in the where clause to identify default value

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3, column-defaults

I am trying to write a query that tells if a column named `s` in table `a.t` has its default value (which is a very big base64 string). So I tried:

```
SELECT 1 FROM a.t WHERE s = (
   SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns
   WHERE (table_schema, table_name, column_name) = ('a', 't', 's'))
   AND uname = 'joe';
```

Which didn't work, so I noticed that the result from `information_schema.columns` had some stuff on it that the regular query did not:

```
SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE (table_schema, table_name, column_name) = ('a', 't', 's');

column_default | 'data:image/png;base64,iVBO...QmCC'::text
```

Vs.

```
SELECT s FROM a.t WHERE uname = 'joe';

s | data:image/png;base64,iVBO...QmCC
```

Note the lack of quotes and explicit cast.
Is this why it does not match? Column `s` is defined as type `text`.
How can I change my query so I can test for equality between the column value and its default?

Comment: Sorry I didn't think it mattered much, but it's 9.3

Comment: As long as you don't know all possible solutions, any or all of them can depend on the version in use. For instance, `format()` was introduced with version 9.1 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you retrieve from the information schema (or the system catalogs in my solution) is just **a string literal representing the expression**. You need to actually *execute* it to get ***value***. It can be a trivial cast like in your case or *any* other expression. That's where you need **dynamic SQL**. (Or concatenate a second query in your client from the results of the first query.)

Detailed explanation in this related answer:
[Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357)
<sub>(You'll also find instructions for an alternative route ***without*** dynamic SQL over there.)</sub>

This [`DO` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) does the trick.

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _data text := 'data:image/png;base64,iVBO...QmCC';
   _answer bool;
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('SELECT %s = $1', d.adsrc)
   FROM   pg_attribute a 
   JOIN   pg_attrdef   d ON (d.adrelid, d.adnum) = (a.attrelid, a.attnum)
   WHERE  a.attrelid = 'a.t'::regclass   -- schema.table
   AND    a.attname = 's'
   )
USING  _data
INTO   _answer;

RAISE NOTICE '%', answer;

END
$do$;
```

For repeated use I would wrap this into a plpgsql function. There are many related answers.

Also be aware that **column defaults can have side effects** like increasing a sequence. Not in this particular case, but generally I'd advise to check the default *before* executing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I don't need a general solution but now I  understand what is happening, so I realize I can just select `left(right(column_default, -1), -7)` from the info schema and get it to work.

Comment: @user9645: You may also be interested in the alternative route without dynamic SQL I applied in [the other answer I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357). Basically: create a temp copy of the table and insert a dummy row (which materializes a default value).