# Get default column value when referencing view SQL / Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

How can I get the default value for a column if I can only reference a view, which is a composite of multiple tables?  Rather, is it even feasible?

Disregard permissions for the time being.  How to get the default value for a column from a table directly is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146448/get-the-default-values-of-table-columns-in-postgres), however that is insufficient because if I query for the default value of the column in the view, it reasonably returns nothing/null.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out, which table the column originates from. You can query the **system catalogs**:

```
SELECT definition
FROM   pg_views
WHERE  viewname = 'my_view'
AND    schemaname = 'public';
```

Or get the view definition in **psql** with:

```
\d+ my_view
```

Or just look it up in the object browser in **pgAdmin**.
Then you can proceed from there with the techniques you already found:

- [Get the default values of table columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146448/get-the-default-values-of-table-columns-in-postgres)

Or, to get an actual *value*, not just the expression to compute it:

- [Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357)

Comment: Hi Erwin.  Great, I am able to get the view definitions as described.  Lucky for me, my tables are named similarly (common prefix).  Thus, hopefully I should be able to parse thru the names/cols, and extract the data as proposed.  Thanks a again sir!