# Inserting a COALESCE(NULL,default)

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have tables that use UUIDs. I want to be able to insert a new row with or without a UUID as sometimes the client will generate the UUID other times it won't.

Each table has this at it's core:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
);
```

I'm trying to use a function to insert rows. I'd like to be able to hand a NULL id and get a default value (a generated UUID). I have something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_person(
    id UUID
) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO person( id )
    VALUES (
        COALESCE(id,default)
    );
    RETURN FOUND;
END;
$$;
```

I've tried this:

```
INSERT INTO person ( id ) VALUES (
    COALESCE(id, default),
);
```

and this:

```
INSERT INTO person ( id ) VALUES (
  CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN default ELSE id END
);
```

This works, but it repeats the gen_random_uuid() code:

```
INSERT INTO person ( id ) VALUES (
  COALESCE(id, gen_random_uuid()),
);
```

similarly this works too but has the same problems:

```
INSERT INTO person ( id ) VALUES (
    CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN gen_random_uuid() ELSE id END
);
```

Is there a way to do this where I don't have to repeat the `gen_random_uuid()` code?

Would this be better done with `plpgsql`?

Comment: As you are using PL/pgSQL, I would use an `if id is not null then insert .. values (id) else insert ... values (default)`

Comment: What is this `default`? I cannot see where it's defined. Is that visible? Can you print it? Another angle is: I would try to name this `default` something else that's not an SQL keyword, like `default_value`.

Comment: @tamas-rev It's the `default` keyword that I want. I would like Postgres to insert a default value there (as defined in the CREATE TABLE).

Comment: @horse_with_no_name Thanks for the suggestion. The issue there is, in reality, there are other fields that have defaults that I would also like to be auto-filled. For instance in the real version of this `person` table there is a `timezone` field that needs to autofill to something sensible.

Comment: One thought was to always do a create with default values and then do an update immediately as part of the function. It feels a bit wrong to me.

Comment: I think, the `case when is is null ...` solution is fine. You can replace the `gen_random_uuid()` with another custom function. So you can tweak the UUID generating algorithm at one place. Still, you have to wire the function name into every `insert into` clause.

Comment: @tamas-rev the problem there is that if anyone creates a person without using the function it won't get a UUID (unless I repeat the `gen_random_uuid()`—which I can do, but it feels wrong!)

Comment: I think triggers can help you. E.g they can run something `before insert` for you. I can't test it because I don't have postgres on my machine. However, [this page](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/) is a good place to start.

Comment: Third time lucky I think tamas has the right answer. `BEFORE INSERT` Triggers let you change the values of any insert and swap out nulls for a new value.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that, I already use a trigger for keeping a revision counter. I'll give that a go, thanks @philip-couling

Comment: Thanks  @tamas-rev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to re-use the defined default on the column.  The default is only there to define what happens if an `INSERT` doesn't specify a value.  By this definition a `null` value is still "specified" and therefore default can't be used.

Your comment that someone might not use the function indicates that a trigger is better for your requirements than a simple function.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION default_id() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $default_id$
    BEGIN       
        IF (NEW.id IS NULL) THEN
            NEW.id := gen_random_uuid();
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$default_id$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER default_id_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON person
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE default_id();
```

---

If you do want to do this with a function then the simplest way is just to assign the value before inserting:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_person(
    id UUID
) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF id IS NULL THEN
        id := gen_random_uuid();
    END IF;
    -- OR
    -- id := coalesce(id, gen_random_uuid());
    INSERT INTO person( id )
    VALUES (id);
    RETURN FOUND;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: It looks like that won't work, either. `id` is a `PRIMARY KEY` and therefore cannot be `NULL`.

    `PostgreSQL said: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: Are you sure you created a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` and not `AFTER INSERT`. I've just tested this and it works fine for `INTEGER` so I see no reason why it doesn't for `UUID`.

Comment: Indeed I had. This seems to work fine for me now. Thanks!

Comment: @Sambeau Notice that a trigger is an obscure element in the db design and it can be confusing for a non experienced SQL developer in more than one way.

Comment: @clodoaldo-neto I realise. Thanks for your help. This is mostly a learning exercise for me and an experiment with client-generated UUIDs and table revisions. It's not for production yet.

Answer (score 9):

The core problem is the special nature of the key word `DEFAULT` in a `VALUES` expression attached to an `INSERT`. [Per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html#AEN89091):

> In a `VALUES` list appearing at the top level of an `INSERT`, an
>   expression can be replaced by `DEFAULT` to indicate that the destination
>   column's default value should be inserted. **`DEFAULT` cannot be used when
>   `VALUES` appears in other contexts.**

Bold emphasis mine. Specifically, `DEFAULT` cannot be argument to a function:

```
COALESCE(function_parameter, DEFAULT)  -- not possible
```

#### Possible solution

There are various ways, depending on *exact* requirements.

This function doesn't need to know the actual default of `person.id` - which seems to be what you are after:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_person(_id UUID)
  RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER AS
$func$
BEGIN
   IF _id IS NULL THEN                 -- no UUID provided
      INSERT INTO myschema.person(id)  -- see below about schema name
      VALUES (DEFAULT);                -- use the key word DEFAULT
   ELSE                                -- UUID provided
      INSERT INTO myschema.person(id)
      VALUES (_id);
   END IF;

   RETURN FOUND;                       -- (return value pointless so far)
END
$func$;
```

Avoid using the same name for parameters and involved table columns. Since function parameters are visible inside every SQL command in the function body, it can lead to very confusing **naming conflicts** (even if target columns of `INSERT` are exempt from this in modern Postgres). I use `_id` as parameter name instead.

Default values for ***other columns*** not mentioned in the `INSERT` are filled in ***automatically***. I use the key word `DEFAULT` because we are required to list at least one target column for the `INSERT`.

The `boolean` return value is pointless in this demo because it is *always* `true` (unless you have triggers that might skip the row).

Related answer with possible alternatives and a lot of explanation:

- [Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357)

Aside: You should schema-qualify ***all*** function and table names in a `SECURITY DEFINER` function - ***or*** (probably better if you aren't sure) explicitly set the `search_path` to defend against possible attacks. More:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Great answer, I think I have another work around.  I'm pulling metadata and have entries like `nextval('schema.table_id_seq'::regclass)` which (at least in this case) works in the COALESCE.

Answer (score -1):

Overload the `gen_random_uuid` function:

```
create or replace function gen_random_uuid()
returns uuid as $$
    select 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11'::uuid;
$$ language sql;


create or replace function gen_random_uuid(_id uuid)
returns uuid as $$
    select coalesce(_id, gen_random_uuid());
$$ language sql;
```

Create the table as usual:

```
create table if not exists person (
    id uuid default gen_random_uuid()
);
```

Call the `gen_random_uuid` function inside the `create_person` function:

```
create or replace function create_person(_id uuid)
returns boolean as $$
    insert into person (id) values (gen_random_uuid(_id))
    returning true;
$$ language sql;
```

Then all the insert variations will work:

```
insert into person (id) values (default);
select create_person(null);
select create_person('b1eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a22'::uuid);
```

Comment: Sometimes I *have* to pass an id to the create function. That's the whole point when using UUIDs. Sometimes the server will create an object, sometimes a client will.

Comment: @Sambeau It sounds like bad design

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it only works because you dropped `PRIMARY KEY` from id. If you put it back you get
`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "person_pkey"`
`DETAIL:  Key (id)=(a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11) already exists.`

Comment: @Sambeau I droped the primary key because my dummy `gen_random_uuid` function always returns the same uuid. If it generated a random one it would work with a primary key.

Comment: My apologies. I see that now. That does indeed work.

Comment: However it still has `insert into person (id) values (gen_random_uuid(_id))` so it's basically equivalent to `COALESCE(id, gen_random_uuid())`